# Breaking up a message to be readable while coding in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have this function, written from another post, except I am running into an issue where my messages need to be wordy so the end user doesn't panic, that being said, how do I break a sentence below so it will be readable while I am coding?

I hope this makes sense... thanks.

```
Function GetErrMsg(ErNo As Long) As String
    Select Case ErNo
        Case 91
            GetErrMsg = "This is a long message that needs to be broken into sections so it can be read normally in the programming box"
    End Select
End Function
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Underscore `_` to break up lines of code like this:

```
Function GetErrMsg(ErNo As Long) As String
    Select Case ErNo
        Case 91
           GetErrMsg = "This is a long message that needs to be broken into " & _ 
                "sections so it can be read normally in the programming box"
    End Select
End Function
```

**Note**

When breaking up strings you need to end the string with a `"`

Then add the ampersand `&` to concatenate before the underscore `_`like in the above example.

This tells VBA that the string is over, but will be joined to the string on the next line.